Crystallographic Specific Mean Free Path (MFP) Derivations: High-Symmetry Direction Mapping and Band Slope Selection
In the given paper,(Paper Link) Figure 4 describes the Mean Free Path (MFP) for the three crystallographic directions (100, 110, and 111). The Methods section mentions that the MFPs are obtained using velocities computed from the slope of the GW band structure along these high-symmetry directions. The GW band structure is derived for the bulk material.
My query is how to know the reciprocal space i.e. high
symmetry path corresponding to given crystallographic directions?

